# Joomla 3 Make User-Profile Field Available on Back End Only

Tags: joomla3.0, user-profile

Joomla v3.6.4

I want to re-purpose one of the user profile fields, for example address2, for administrative use. I want the field available on the back end but not appear (or be read-only) on the front end. I configured the user-profile plug-in to make address2 Optional on the back end and Disabled on the front end.

However, when a user edits his profile on the front end, the data is removed from the disabled field. I tried editing `plugins/user/profile/profiles/profile.xml` to make the field read-only, but this also makes it read-only on the back end. Any suggestions to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a custom field or you can created your own custom profile type plugin. https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.